# How to use scapy with ip length > 20 and ip option 0

Tags: scapy

How do I send a packet with Scapy that has a ip length > 20 and the first byte of ip option == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to craft the packet:

```
>>> packet = Ether() / IP(options='\x00')
```

Note that the IP header length (IHL) goes up in multiples of 4 bytes, so the length is now 24 bytes:

```
>>> packet.show2()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src= 00:00:00:00:00:00
  type= 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version= 4
     ihl= 6
     tos= 0x0
     len= 24
     id= 1
     flags=
     frag= 0
     ttl= 64
     proto= hopopt
     chksum= 0x7be3
     src= 127.0.0.1
     dst= 127.0.0.1
     \options\
      |###[ IP Option End of Options List ]###
      |  copy_flag= 0
      |  optclass= control
      |  option= end_of_list
      |###[ IP Option End of Options List ]###
      |  copy_flag= 0
      |  optclass= control
      |  option= end_of_list
      |###[ IP Option End of Options List ]###
      |  copy_flag= 0
      |  optclass= control
      |  option= end_of_list
      |###[ IP Option End of Options List ]###
      |  copy_flag= 0
      |  optclass= control
      |  option= end_of_list
```

If you want to send it, you can use the sendp function:

```
>>> sendp(packet)
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

If you want to address it to another host, set `dst='192.168.1.1'` or similar to the IP layer of the packet. Scapy will automatically set the other fields (Ethernet source, destination, IP source) appropriately.